# Finding first location of maximum value in a range (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have a range in Excel and I want to find the first location that contains the maximum value (the max might not be unique, but I only want to find the first place it appears).

This is what I came up with:
[image]

My question is whether there is a more succinct way to do this? The part of the formula that's doing all the work is MATCH(MAX(MyRange),MyRange,0) which will return the position of the element I want. I would like to have the formula in column C be something like:

= MATCH(MAX(MyRange),MyRange,0) = ...

but I'm not sure how to finish. I don't know how to get the position of a value in MyRange (i.e., B4 is the first position, B5 is the second, etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
= MATCH(MAX(MyRange),MyRange,0)+MIN(ROW(MyRange))-1 = ROW()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! MIN(ROW(MyRange)) was the bit I was missing.